# Is it possible to reduce the charging current?

Tags: rooting, charging, hardware

I'd like to reduce the charging current of my phone, because

- It gets too hot
- I am charging it overnight so it's more beneficial to charge it slowly.

Is it even possible from a hardware perspective to regulate the charging power (e.g. reduce it from say 2000mA to 1000mA)?

I tried to search on google but not only that I didn't find any apps that would be able to accomplish it - I didn't even find anyone discussing it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the magisk module [advanced charging controller (AAC)](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/acc), which let's you set the maximal current to whatever you want using the shell command `aac --set --current {milliamperes}`.